# SQL - replace nulls with 0 in custom table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I've got really weird logic where I getting my custom table with custom nullable fields.

How can I change all NULL values in the table to 0 ?

Sorry but with custom fields I mean that
**I don't know the name of columns !**

Comment: I would leave the null values rather than change to zero without knowing what the column is. Zero might have meaning in some of these columns and in others might not even be an allowable value. A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By querying sys.columns and sys.objects you can generate a query that alters every column to a default value (specified by you) for the column types you want to set a default non-null value for.

Something like this will give you something to look at:

```
SELECT  so.name, 
        sc.name AS varname ,
        st.name AS typename ,
        sc.max_length ,
        sc.[precision] ,
        sc.scale ,
        sc.collation_name
FROM    sys.columns sc
        JOIN SYS.types st ON sc.system_type_id = st.system_type_id
                             AND sc.user_type_id = st.user_type_id
        JOIN sys.objects so ON so.object_id = sc.object_id
```

You can then attach a cursor for this and run a series of alter/update commands based on typename (column type) and varname (column name).

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE custom_table
   SET the_column = 0
 WHERE the_column IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean in ALL columns, then you could do a very expensive query that will touch all records and columns:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET
col1 = isnull(col1, 0),
col2 = isnull(col2, 0),
col3 = isnull(col3, 0),
col4 = isnull(col4, 0),
col5 = isnull(col5, 0)
-- etc all the numeric columns *
```

- If you included date columns, they go to '1900-01-01'

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE mytable SET mycol=0 WHERE mycol IS NULL